# wso2GadgetServer: How to use a proxy?

Tags: wso2

I installed the wso2GadgetServer-1.4.2 within our company network. Access to external datasources is available via proxy. Within the /repository/conf/wrapper.conf I added the following:

```
wrapper.java.additional.11=-Dhttp.proxyHost=<ip of our proxy>
wrapper.java.additional.12=-Dhttp.proxyPort=<port the proxy is listening to>
wrapper.java.additional.13=-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=127.0.0.1|localhost
```

I (re-)started the GadgetServer and opened the dashboard again. The (external) content of the (predefined) gadget was not displayed. Instead a timeout message was shown.  Within the /repository/logs/wrapper.logs I found corresponding entries like the following:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/04/12 08:24:21 | Apr 12, 2012 8:24:20 AM org.apache.shindig.gadgets.servlet.ProxyBase outputError
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/04/12 08:24:21 | Warnung: Request failed
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/04/12 08:24:21 | org.apache.shindig.gadgets.GadgetException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to soa-platform.blogspot.com/209.85.148.132:80 timed out
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/04/12 08:24:21 |   at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.http.BasicHttpFetcher.fetch(BasicHttpFetcher.java:351)
[...]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/04/12 08:24:21 | Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to soa-platform.blogspot.com/209.85.148.132:80 timed out
```

**Does anybody have an idea, how to resolve the problem?**

btw: 2 guys adressed the same problem at http://wso2.org/forum/thread/21081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the article [WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 - Configure forward proxy for client software](http://peterverschueren.blogspot.de/2012/03/wso2-esb-403-configure-forward-proxy.html) I have found a solution. If the `http.` is removed from the configuration, then the external content of the gadget is displayed:

```
wrapper.java.additional.11=-DproxyHost=<ip of our proxy>
wrapper.java.additional.12=-DproxyPort=<port the proxy is listening to>
wrapper.java.additional.13=-DnonProxyHosts=127.0.0.1|localhost
```